# Scraping HTML data from a page that adds new tables as you scroll

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

Im trying to learn html scraping for a project, I'm using python and lxml. I've been successful so far in getting the data I needed but now I have another problem. The site that I'm scraping from (op.gg) when you scroll down it adds new tables with more information. When I run my script (below) it only gets the first 50 entries and nothing more. My question is how can I get at least the first 200 names on the page or if it is even possible.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://na.op.gg/ranking/ladder/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

names = tree.xpath('//td[@class="SummonerName Cell"]/a/text()')

print (names)
```

Comment: `https://na.op.gg/ranking/ajax2/ladders/start=0` , then `https://na.op.gg/ranking/ajax2/ladders/start=50` and so on...

Comment: `page = requests.get('https://na.op.gg/ranking/ajax2/ladders/start=50')`

`tree = html.fromstring(page.content)`

`print(tree.xpath('/html/body/a[2]/text()'))`


@PedroLobito Okay noob question, If I try that I get empty lists, what am I doing wrong? Also sorry about formatting I'm new to using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrow the idea from Pedro, `https://na.op.gg/ranking/ajax2/ladders/start=number` will give you 50 records start from **number**, for example:

`https://na.op.gg/ranking/ajax2/ladders/start=0` get (1-50),

`https://na.op.gg/ranking/ajax2/ladders/start=50` get (51-100),

`https://na.op.gg/ranking/ajax2/ladders/start=100` get (101-150),

`https://na.op.gg/ranking/ajax2/ladders/start=150` get (151-200),

etc....

After that you could change your scrap code, as the page is different as your original one, suppose you want get first 200 names, here is the amended code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

start_url = 'https://na.op.gg/ranking/ajax2/ladders/start='
names_200 = list()
for i in [0,50,100,150]:
    dest_url = start_url + str(i)
    page = requests.get(dest_url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    names_50 = tree.xpath('//a[not(@target) and not(@onclick)]/text()')
    names_200.extend(names_50)
print names_200
print len(names_200)
```

**Output:**

```
[u'am\xc3\xa9liorer', 'pireaNn', 'C9 Ray', 'P1 Pirean', 'Pobelter', 'mulgokizary', 'consensual clown', 'Jue VioIe Grace', 'Deep Learning', 'Keegun', 'Free Papa Chau', 'C9 Gun', 'Dhokla', 'Arrowlol', 'FOX Brandini', 'Jurassiq', 'Win or Learn', 'Acoldblazeolive', u'R\xc3\xa9venge', u'M\xc3\xa9ru', 'Imaqtpie', 'Rohammers', 'blaberfish2', 'qldurtms', u'd\xc3\xa0wolfsclaw', 'TheOddOrange', 'PandaTv 656826', 'stuntopolis', 'Butler Delta', 'P1 Shady', 'Entranced', u'Linsan\xc3\xadty', 'Ablazeolive', 'BukZacH', 'Anivia Kid', 'Contractz', 'Eitori', 'MistyStumpey', 'Prodedgy', 'Splitting', u'S\xc4\x99b B\xc4\x99rnal', 'N For New York', 'Naeun', '5tunt', 'C9 Winter', 'Doubtfull', 'MikeYeung', 'Rikara', u'RAH\xc3\x9cLK', ' Sudzzi', 'joong ki song', 'xWeixin VinLeous', 'rhubarbs', u'Ch\xc3\xa0se', 'XueGao', 'Erry', 'C9 EonYoung', 'Yeonbee', 'M ckg', u'Ari\xc3\xa1na Lovato', 'OmarGod', 'Wiggily', 'lmpactful', 'Str1fe', 'LL Stylish', '2017', 'FlREFLY', 'God Fist Monk', 'rWeiXin VinLeous', 'Grigne', 'fantastic ad', 'bobqinX', 'grigne 1v10', 'Sora1', 'Juuichi san ', 'duoking2', 'SandPaperX', 'Xinthus', 'TwichTv CoMMa', 'xFSN Rin', 'UBC CJ', 'PotIuck', 'DarkWingsForSale', 'Get After lt', 'old chicken', u'\xc4\x86ris', 'VK Deemo', 'Pekin Woof', 'YIlIlIlIlI', 'RiceLegend', 'Chimonaa1', 'DJNDREE5', u'CloudNguy\xc3\xa9n', 'Diamond 1 Khazix', 'dawolfsfang', 'clg imaqtpie69', 'Pyrites', 'Lava', 'Rathma', 'PieCakeLord', 'feed l0rd', 'Eygon', 'Autolycus1', 'FateFalls 20xx', 'nIsHIlEzHIlA', 'C9 Sword', 'TET Fear', 'a very bad time', u'Jur\xc3\xa1ssiq', 'Ginormous Noob', 'Saskioo', 'S D 2 NA', 'C9 Smoothie', 'dufTlalgkqtlek', 'Pants are Dragon', u'H\xc3\xb3llywood', 'Serenitty', 'Waggily ', 'never lucky help', u'insan\xc3\xadty', 'Joyul', 'TheeBrandini', 'FoTheWin', 'RyuShoryu', 'avi is me', 'iKingVex', 'PrismaI', 'An Obese Panda', 'TdollasAKATmoney', 'feud999', 'Soligo', 'Steel I', 'SNH48 Ruri', 'BillyBoss1', 'Annie Bot', 'Descraton', 'Cris', 'GrayHoves', 'RegisZZ', 'lron Pyrite', 'Zaion', 'Allorim', 't d', u'Alex \xc3\xafch', 'godrjsdnd', 'DOUBLELIFTSUCKS', 'John Mcrae', u'Lobo Solitari\xc3\xb3', 'MikeYeunglol', 'i xo u', 'NoahMost', 'Vsionz', 'GladeGleamBright', 'Tuesdayy', 'RealDarkness', 'CC Dean', 'na mid xd LFT', 'Piggy Kitten', 'Abou222', 'TG Strompest', 'MooseHater', 'Day after Day', 'bat8man', 'AxAxAxAxA', 'Boyfriend', 'EvanRL', '63FYWJMbam', 'Fiftygbl', u'Br\xc4\xb1an', 'MlST', u'S\xc3\xb8ren Bjerg', 'FOX Akaadian', '5word', 'tchikou', 'Hakuho', 'Noobkiller291', 'woxiangwanAD', 'Doublelift', 'Jlaol', u'z\xc3\xa3ts', 'Cow Goes Mooooo', u'Be Like \xc3\x91e\xc3\xb8\xc3\xb8', 'Liquid Painless', 'Zergy', 'Huge Rooster', 'Shiphtur', 'Nikkone', 'wiggily1', 'Dylaran', u'C\xc3\xa0m', 'byulbit', 'dirtybirdy82', 'FreeXpHere', u'V\xc2\xb5lcan', 'KaNKl', 'LCS Actor 4', 'bie sha wo', 'Mookiez', 'BKSMOOTH', 'FatMiku']
200
```

BTW, you could expand it based on your requirement.